# Can we add more functions using javascript in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

Hi I am newbie to selenium.

I came to know that goto_sel_ide.js file which was given in one forum which helps to add the functions like gotoIf, while, label etc.,

Can we create javascript for exit and for loop like wise?

Please suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

you should see the [SelBlocks extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-sel-blocks/), as it has breaks.